# count repeated elements in a string

Tags: java, string, algorithm, performance, time-complexity

The question is to find the number of consecutive occurrences of a character '*' in a string.
I've written a program for it but is there any other efficient way to solve this

```
        for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
            if(s.charAt(i) == '*'){
                count=1;
                for(int j=i+1;j<n;j++){
                    if(s.charAt(j) != s.charAt(i))
                        break;
                    else
                        count++;
                }
            }
        }
```

For example:

```
input: *a**b  output should be 2
input: ***a**b output should be 3
```

Comment: this is rather a code review. You could transform your String to an array -> stream -> filter that stream for only the wanted char -> count the number of results

Comment: Please add sample inputs and then point out what your definition of "consecutive occurrence" means here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simpler a bit, linear complexity (the highest possible effectiveness for this task):

```
int stars = 0; 
int longest = 0;
for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
        if(s.charAt(i) == '*') {
            stars++;
            longest = Math.max(longest, stars);
            //here you can do something useful - 
            // for example, get max number of consecutive stars
        }
        else {
            //here you can do something useful - in case of  if (stars > 0) 
            // for example - increment number of series
            //and don't forget to do the same action after loop finish
            stars = 0;
        }      
}
```

Comment: this does not provide the required solution as I need to count the maximum consecutive occurrences of character '*' in the input string. Your solution does not count consecutive occurrences but counts the total number of  '*' in string

Comment: You did not explain WHAT is required solution, so I proposed some possibilities. And yes, this solution allows to find the longest series in the place `// for example, get max number of consecutive stars` like this `longest = max(longest, stars)`. Have you noticed that counter `stars` becomes zero after every non-star char?

Comment: Thank you. Using `longest = max(longest,stars)` solves the problem

Comment: OK. In your code maxCount is calculated every loop turn.  It is better to move `max` inside `if` to avoid excessive comparisons